# How do I have 2 python server/client apps running on 2 virtual machines so they can communicate (send messages) between each other?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, client-server

I want to create a simple Python 3 client/sever program on two VMs.

**VM 1 IP Address = 10.0.0.3**

**VM 2 IP Address = 10.0.0.2**

**The goal:** Is to have VM 1 and VM 2 be able to communicate between each other -- i.e. send messages from VM 1 to VM 2 and VM 2 to VM 1

**My issue:** Is that I don't know/understand how VM 1 can communicate back to VM 2. I mean, how does communication happen on both sides.

My understanding is that I need a server.py file on VM 2 and a client.py file on VM 1 as well right?

But when I tried to the server.py file on VM 1 and client.py file on VM 2 it works perfectly. I am able to send messages from VM 1 to VM 2. The issue arises when I start server.py on VM 2 and client.py on VM 1. As soon as I start client.py on VM 1, both the client.py processes quit and the servers are still running.

I changed the port numbers so VM 2 -> VM 1 is communicating on port 4455, and VM 1 -> VM 2 is communicating on 4456 but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions? Am I doing this completely wrong?

Here is the code

**server.py on VM 1**

```py
import socket
import sys

sockethost = ""
socketport = 4455

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((SOCKETHOST, SOCKETPORT))

s.listen()


while True:
    connection, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to -> " + str(address[0]) + " on port -> " + str(address[1]))
    message = input(str("Input -> "))
    message = message.encode()

    connection.send(message)
```

**client.py on VM 2**

```py
import socket
import sys

sockethost = "10.0.0.3"
SOCKETPORT = 4455

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((sockethost, SOCKETPORT))

while True:
    incoming_mess = s.recv(2048)
    incoming_mess = incoming_mess.decode()
    print("Server -> ", incoming_mess)
    print()
```

**server.py on VM 2**

```py
import socket
import sys

sockethost = ""
socketport = 4456

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((SOCKETHOST, SOCKETPORT))

s.listen()


while True:
    connection, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to -> " + str(address[0]) + " on port -> " + str(address[1]))
    message = input(str("Input -> "))
    message = message.encode()

    connection.send(message)
```

**client.py on VM 1**

```py
import socket
import sys

sockethost = "10.0.0.2"
SOCKETPORT = 4456

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((sockethost, SOCKETPORT))

while True:
    incoming_mess = s.recv(2048)
    incoming_mess = incoming_mess.decode()
    print("Server -> ", incoming_mess)
    print()
```

Again, any suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.